# AttributedText on MvxTableViewCell

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm trying to set underline on UILabel of MvxTableViewCell.

```
    [Register("KittenCell")]
    public class KittenCell : MvxTableViewCell
    {
        private UIImageView MainImage;
        private UILabel NameLabel;
        private UILabel PriceValueLabel;
        private UILabel PriceLabel;

        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("KittenCell");
        private MvxImageViewLoader imageLoader;

        public KittenCell ()
        {
            CreateLayout ();
            InitializeBindings ();
        }

        public KittenCell(IntPtr handle)
            : base(handle) 
        {
            CreateLayout ();
            InitializeBindings ();
        }

        void CreateLayout ()
        {
            MainImage = new UIImageView (new RectangleF (0, 0, 160, 100));

            NameLabel = new UILabel (new RectangleF (168, 15, 144, 21));
            NameLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left;
            var attrs = new UIStringAttributes {
                UnderlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.Single
            };
            NameLabel.AttributedText =new NSAttributedString(NameLabel.Text,attrs);

            PriceLabel = new UILabel (new RectangleF (168, 59, 57, 21));
            PriceLabel.Text = "Price:";
            PriceLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left;
            PriceValueLabel = new UILabel (new RectangleF (228, 59, 84, 21));
            PriceValueLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left;
            PriceValueLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Blue;
            ContentView.AddSubviews (MainImage, NameLabel, PriceLabel, PriceValueLabel);
        }

        void InitializeBindings ()
        {
            imageLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader (() => this.MainImage);

            this.DelayBind (() => {
                var set = this.CreateBindingSet<KittenCell, Kitten> ();
                set.Bind (NameLabel).To(kitten => kitten.Name);
                set.Bind (PriceValueLabel).To(kitten => kitten.Price);
                set.Bind (imageLoader).To(kitten => kitten.ImageUrl);
                set.Apply ();
            });

        }
    }
```

but when UILabel is shown there is no underline under it. My explanation is that underline is applied on text that is not already binded. But how is possible to set it after binding?

Comment: Create binding for AttributedText and use that for binding rather then Text property. Let me know if you need a detailed explanation and I will post a proper answer.

Comment: @MohibSheth Yes could you add an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a converter something along this:

```
public class UnderlineTextValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, NSAttributedString>
    {
        protected override NSAttributedString Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            var attrs = new UIStringAttributes {
                UnderlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.Single
            };
            return new NSAttributedString(value, attrs);
        }
    }
```

and then update your binding to this...

```
set.Bind (NameLabel).For(l => l.AttributedText).To(kitten => kitten.Name).WithConversion("UnderlineText", null);
```

The above code is untested, but it should work with no or little modification.